# "Relationship may be needed" although relationship is set

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

I have two simple table in Excel 2010 - Products and Sales:
[image]

I then linked them into PowerPivot - and here created the relationship from Sales.ProductId to Products.Id - like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to build a Pivot that for each productId in the Sales table also shows me the Category and the PurchasePrice from the ProductTable. However, here I'm stuck - because the relationship is somehow faulty. When configuring the Pivot, I get a message `Relationship may be needed` even if the relationship already exists. The resulting - wrong - pivot table looks like this:[image]

though I'm actually trying to achieve this:
[image]

I know that I could create calculated columns in the Sales table of PowerPivot and pull all required data using the `RELATED` DAX function - but as the real world project requires a lot of joins and fields I'm hoping that there's a better solution than this workaround...

I uploaded the example file [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!TBI2nSgb!TlJh06Y2TwthcBdPBY-9D0x0QSOIOw7zdJ7Y5U5CMQw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Peter**,

Your question was a bit more tricky than I first though and I spent quite some time digging around, but I think I found the solution after reading this [article about making distinct count in related tables](http://www.daxpatterns.com/distinct-count/).

I have updated your source file (so that *Sales* table contains more than 1 sales per product) and [uploaded it to my public Dropbox folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/258211/sample.xlsb).

You can see that I created 4 new *calculated measures* to illustrate my solution and to make it a bit easier to understand (Excel 2010 terminology, in 2013 it's *Calculated Field*):

**Sales Price Total**

```
=SUM(Sales[SalesPrice])
```

**Products Sold**

```
=COUNT(Sales[ProductId])
```

**Purchase Price per Item**

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Products[PurchasePrice]),Sales)
```

**Purchase Price Total**

```
=[Purchase Price per Item] * [Product Sold]
```

The key difference here is the formula for calculating **purchase price per item**. The reason why you should *SUM* the product purchase price within *CALCULATE* function is explained in great detail in the [linked article](http://www.daxpatterns.com/distinct-count/) (even though in a bit different context):

> In this way, any filter active on Sales (the related table) propagates
>   to the lookup table.

There might be some other parts I missed, but I have tried this in couple other examples and it simply works as it should:

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm, confusing.m and I thought I found the answer :) Let me check that today and I will update my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Peter, I have rewrote my answer completely, hopefully now it will be helpful and provide you with the solution. It took me some time to realize this and it's a bit misleading how relationship in PowerPivot works...

Comment: Thanks a lot - this looks really interesting, will go through it in detail later today! +1 already :-)

Comment: Glad I could help Peter. If you are happy with the answer, could you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks!